# Is it possible to fire the index.html page after beeing deployed as «Folder»?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm just doing some testing with Blazor WebAssembly (Client side). So I created a project in NET Core 8 and deployed published it to «Folder».

Now I'd like to fire my page by double-clicking the «index.html» page, but it seems that some more tweeking is needed.

So, Im wondering, what needs to be done to get what I want. Does Blazor allways needs some kind of server suport?

I'd apreciated any help.

Thanks.

---

ADDED:

After publishin I got this folder structure:
[image]

Then I modified   to   and tryed reload, Then got this error
[image]
Looking more closely:
[image]

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Blazor allways needs some kind of server suport?

Yes, you will need a server. Modern browsers don't allow much outside of the beaten path.

You can tweak it to use  `<base href="./" />` and then the base _framework/blazor.webassembly.js and the css styles will load.

But the dynamic loading of other (js) modules will fail with

> Access to script at 'file:///D:/Source/.../publish/wwwroot/_framework/dotnet.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https, edge.

And thus not for schema file://

Comment: Does selenium has the same behavor? Thats because in my scenario I use selenium to show pages using JQuery, etc, and I'd like to try Blazor.